# To what extent has the war on terror in the Somalia achieved its goals?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, military, africa

Has it been at all effective in getting rid of Al-Shabaab? How has it affected the region?
Edit: I mean the US-led [Operation Enduring Freedom - Horn of Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Enduring_Freedom_%E2%80%93_Horn_of_Africa).

Comment: By "the war on terror in Somalia", do you mean the Ethiopia-led intervention of 2006-2009, in which the US took part?

Comment: I mean the US-led intervention which is still going on today

Comment: @sfxedit I've specified.

Comment: @edelex just a friendly advice to a new user.  don't assume that you are understood just because you alluded to something.  people mostly read this site casually.  they don't try to put their heart and soul into analyzing every little detail you think is important.  a pedantic description will usually do better than an insightful description here.

Comment: One element to consider is what *not* having an anti-Shahaab mission could have resulted in.  I.e. a stalemate may look bad compared to a mission statement of removing Al-Shahaab.  But it compares rather favorably to having the entire country run by Al-Shahaab.  Religious terrorist-run states are a bummer for everyone, not least the locals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To what extent has the war on terror in the Somalia achieved its
> goals?

Somalia has gone from anarchy and rule by warlords to a fragile national government with some semblance of peace and rule of law.

Likewise, Somalian piracy, which peaked from 2009-2011, has basically ended.

The fundamentalist Islamist group Al-Shabab's last notable effort killed more than 100 people in car bombings on October 29, 2022 in Mogadishu (a city it controlled until 2011), and it was pushed out of all major cities by mid-2015. But it isn't entirely gone.

Who gets credit for this?

It is hard to say.

As the eons old aphorism that John F. Kennedy repeated explains:

> Victory has a thousand fathers, but defeat is an orphan.

The US-led Operation Enduring Freedom - Horn of Africa played some role, as did U.S. military intervention as far back as 1991.

But, the UN Security Council approved African Union peacekeeping force, AMISOM, with about 19,000 troops as of April 1, 2022, with whom the U.S. troops played a supporting role, from 2007-2022 (when it was replaced by the African Union Transition Mission in Somalia, ATMIS, which takes a secondary and supporting role to the Somalian military), as well as the newly recreated military of the Somalian government, starting around 2012, probably played the predominant role.